# I don't understand this notation... - Series with ln

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, notation, summation

I found this notation in my book
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln^n3
$$
and I don't know how to interpret it.

Is it
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln((1^n)\cdot3)\;?
$$

And btw, how to check if this series converges?

Comment: Maybe it is $(\ln 3)^n$

Comment: It is either $(\ln 3)^n$ or $\underbrace{\ln( \ln ( \dots ( \ln}_{n} (3)) \dots ))$. I think it is the first one.

Comment: It's a finite summation, so it has to converge.

Comment: $\ln^n 3$ should mean $\underbrace{\ln(\ln(\dots \ln}_n(3)\dots))$, but it is more likely $(\ln 3)^n$.

Comment: It is unlikely to be iterated logarithm since it quickly becomes logarithm of a negative number. So I vote for $(\ln 3)^n$.

Comment: ok, it's $$ (ln3)^n  $$
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Note that the index of summation is $i$, so we are simply adding $(\ln 3)^n$ to itself $n$ times, getting $n(\ln 3)^n$. There is no convergence issue. Perhaps there is a typo in the original question, or in your rendition of it.

Comment: Either this is a question written in a very sloppy fashion or else it is a trivial, almost silly, one...

Comment: @TomDavies92

   log 3 > 1  (lets say 1.3)
  so 1.3 + 1.3^2 + 1.3^3 +..... 1.3^n   definitely increases as n increases
 and hence divergent

Also please check my another answer below and accept if looks easy to you for understanding?

Comment: @ArnabDutta This is a finite sum. It must converge.

Comment: @MathMajor
I didn't get you
Do you mean:   if n go on increasing, then How f(x) converges?   It should if 0< x  <1, but x= ln 3 >1.

Could you please give  a simple example in this context?

Comment: @Arnab30Dutta It is a properly of the real numbers, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x+y \in \mathbb{R}$, we can do this finitely many times.

Comment: @Arnab30Dutta For example it is clear that $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i$$ diverges yet $$\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer what I think you were *trying* to ask. You asked if the series converges. The series you typed is a finite series, but if it were an infinite series it would diverge because:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n{\ln^n(3)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln^n(3)$$

Also, if the series were written as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\ln^k(3)$$

It would still diverge, because it is a geometric series, and a geometric series converges only if the absolute value of the base is less than $1$. $\ln(3)>1$, so the above series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

@TomDavies92

I think the simple answer he asks for is - What does the Generating function 
$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln^n3 $ means:

The above expression should be better written as: $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln^i3 $

Answer simple, Its expansion is:
$ln\ 3 + ln^2\ 3 + ln^3\ 3 + ...ln^n\ 3 $
                                 $ = ln\ 3 + (ln\ 3)^2 + (ln\ 3)^3 + ...(ln\ 3)^n$  -------(1)

Now:
$ln3 >1$            ( lets say $ln3 = 1.3$)

So equation (1) =$1.3 + 1.3^2+1.3^3+....+1.3^n$ which definitely increases as n increase.
Hence divergent.

Comment: I wish some one to vote me up!